# How to report *amsart* bugs? (Looks like a bug to me.)

Tags: debugging, amsart

I have noticed the following strange behavior when using a custom counter in certain situations in *amsart* document class.  Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\newcounter{exercise}
\newcommand{\exercise}{\stepcounter{exercise}
                       \subsection*{Exercise \theexercise}}
\begin{document}
\exercise
% Text.
\exercise
\end{document}
```

This prints 2 times "Exercise 2".  The behavior goes back to "normal" if i either:

1. replace `amsart` with `article`, or
2. replace `\subsection` with `\section`, or
3. uncomment the text "`Text.`".

This will not cause a problem in a useful document because when there is some text between `\exercise`'s, the problem goes away, but i think this can indicate some bug in *amsart*, so i wanted to report it, but i didn't find where.  What should i do?

Comment: To avoid this, you need to set something that is a non-heading. For this, you could use `\newcommand{\exercise}{\stepcounter{exercise}\subsection*{Exercise \theexercise}\mbox{}}` for your definition of `\exercise`.

Comment: @Werner or better just use the subsection counter as intended instead of a new exercise counter

Comment: the e-mail address for reporting bugs to ams is included in the comments at the top of every file distributed by ams.  or, in this case, as david points out, since this is a "required" latex file, it can be reported via the `latex-bugs` facility.  but, as david also says, this isn't a bug, but a feature based on how `\subsection` is defined.  you might consider an alternative approach, though -- the `\newtheorem` facility would seem to fit nicely, using `\theoremstyle{definition}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, exercises are not subsections, there is no reason to try to use subsection counter to count exercises. This also would not work if i have both subsections and exercises.

Comment: @Alexey well in that case don't use the subsection command:-) You should _copy_ the definition of subsection (which is only a couple of lines) using your own counter.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, i was looking for a quickest hack.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can report AMS bugs direct to them or using the LaTeX bug database form at

http://www.latex-project.org/bugs.html

(category AMS LaTeX).

This isn't really a bug though as `\subsubsection` is an *inline* heading in the AMS class and so the heading doesn't get set until the following paragraph starts. The standard LaTeX sectioning code takes care of the counter increment but if you suppress that with `*` but then simply `\stepcounter` your own counter this will not work (nor can you `\label` the section.)

You see identical behaviour with `\paragraph*` in `article` class.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newcommand{\exercise}{\subsection{}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{Exercise \arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\exercise
% Text.
\exercise
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain please what *inline heading* is, or give a link to where it is explained?

Comment: Ok, i've understood what it is.  I am still wondering however why inline headings behave like this.

Comment: Headings in latex are either display (block) headings where the heading has vertical space between it and the following paragraph or inline headings where the heading is set as part of the first line of the paragraph. in article the lowest level heading set inline is `\paragraph` but amsart sets `\subsection` and below inline.  The latex companion or other latex tutorials should have details or just search this site for `\@startsection`

Comment: @Alexey The heading is held back and not set until the start of the paragraph, and in the usage you have you have _already_ incremented the counter a second time by the time the first heading is set.